# Why I cannot change the graphics card on Linux Mint 19?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, graphics

[image]

NVIDIA is selected in nvidia-settings, however system info shows that the graphics card being used is Intel Graphics.

So, am I interpreting something wrong?

If not, why this does not work?

Thanks.

edit: I figured out that nvidia does not show up in `lspci` quest with "VGA".

```
muyustan@mint:~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915

muyustan@mint:~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "nvidia*"
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: Some computers have an option to disable the default graphics in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The pic is the nvidia config, not the driver selection !
You have to switch drivers see in the 'Drivers' program :
[image]